# Qt Creator autocomplete doesn't recognize std::function<..> (but it recognizes function<..>)?

Tags: c++, c++11, autocomplete, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator 3.0.1 (since that's the version on the repo for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, which I have).

```
#include <functional>
std::function<double(double)> some_func;
```

Here, autocomplete won't recognize `std::function`. If I righ-click that and select "Follow Symbol Under Cursor", it won't work.

However, if I write instead:

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
function<double(double)> some_func;
```

it works fine. This time autocomplete shows up while I am writing `function`, and if I right-click `function` and select "Follow Symbol Under Cursor", it will take me to the declaration of `function` in the `functional` header of the standard library.

What's going on here? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I've seen this issue as well with QT Creator 3.4.1. I think it's best to post a bug report to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG/

Comment: @egore911 I don't have access to that link (my proxy blocks https). Anyone else please file the bug report.